500GB MX500 in too good shape after 588TBW?
One of my Crucial MX500's has a huge TBW value (I'm thinking it was caused by a wrong Windows migration).
The factory specified tbw is 180, but Smartctl measures 588TBW on this one.
Could this be real or a software bug?
First I ran a short and a conveyance self-test on it, both passed.
The long stuck with an error, so I did a destruct on it with the KDE partition manager.
Now the long runs without errors and if I read it right, there are plenty of spare sectors.
Do you think this SSD is still usable?
I attach the smartctl and badblocks report below:
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (  30) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x0031) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  5 Reallocate_NAND_Blk_Cnt 0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       8039
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       53
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Ave_Block-Erase_Count   0x0032   247   247   000    Old_age   Always       -       5488
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       18
180 Unused_Reserve_NAND_Blk 0x0033   000   000   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       47
183 SATA_Interfac_Downshift 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 Error_Correction_Count  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   062   035   000    Old_age   Always       -       38 (Min/Max 0/65)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_ECC_Cnt 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
202 Percent_Lifetime_Remain 0x0030   247   247   001    Old_age   Offline      -       109
206 Write_Error_Rate        0x000e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
210 Success_RAIN_Recov_Cnt  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
246 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1263022909412
247 Host_Program_Page_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       20888923422
248 FTL_Program_Page_Count  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       37710666859

SMART Error Log Version: 1
Invalid Error Log index = 0x07 (T13/1321D rev 1c Section 8.41.6.8.2.2 gives valid range from 1 to 5)

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      8037         -
# 2  Conveyance offline  Completed without error       00%      8012         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      8012         -

badblocks -wsv /dev/sda
Checking for bad blocks in read-write mode
From block 0 to 488386583
Testing with pattern 0xaa: done
Reading and comparing: done
Testing with pattern 0x55: done
Reading and comparing: done
Testing with pattern 0xff: done
Reading and comparing: done
Testing with pattern 0x00: done
Reading and comparing: done
Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)


I don't think we can say. Wear statements will only advise what a failure rate MIGHT be as levels increase. It is up to you what sorts of data you feel confident/safe storing on a drive that has a high wear level. Another factor will be whether what you're seeing is what you THINK you're seeing. How TBW is measured may vary, and that variance may be significant to your purposes.

Thank you for your reply. I added the badblocks report, which shows that there are no bad blocks.
I plan to keep it if it proves to be reliable. I would not produce e-junk unnecessarily.
I would certainly not use it as a main drive or for critical data, was thinking of having in my home server with a nearly new same SSD alongside in raid1. I just don't want it to cause more headaches than it solves.
